# Limit notation/terminology question

Tags: limits, notation

Given an increasing function $f(x)$, I am quite often interested in finding another  (hopefully simpler) function $g(x)$ such that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1 .$$

What is the correct mathematical notation/terminology for expressing the relationship between $f$ and $g$ in this context? It is certainly true that $f(x) \in \Theta(g(x))$ but this doesn't account for constant factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual notation is $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to\infty$; see [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) of Bachmann-Landau notations.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had seen that used without regard to constants but the table is clear, as you suggest.  How would you say that in words?

Comment: @lip1: I’d say that $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equal (as $x\to\infty$), $f$ is asymptotically equal to $g$ (as $x\to\infty$), etc.

Comment: Thanks. What is an "asymptotic approximation" in that case?

Comment: @lip1: I’ve not encountered the term before. My guess would be that $f$ is an asymptotic approximation to $g$ if $f\sim g$.

Comment: OK. Although I hate to accept answers too quicky... Your answer appears perfect.

Comment: @lip1: Thanks. I’m glad that it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

If $f = \Theta(g)$, then $\frac{f}{g} \to c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.  Therefore, we may take the function $cg$, and get that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)} = \frac{1}{c} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{c} \cdot c = 1$$So this gives you a (hopefully) simpler function that has the same asymptotics as $f$.

And @Brian M Scott was spot on with his notation $f $~$ g$

Comment: I am not sure that definition of $\Theta$ is right. In particular, I think you only require that $f(x) \in O(g(x))$ and $f(x) \in \Omega(g(x))$ to have $f(x) \in \Theta(g(x))$ which does not imply that $f(x)/g(x) \rightarrow c$.

Comment: It's an equivalent definition.

Comment: A function $f(x) = (2+\sin(x))x$ is $\Theta(x)$ but $f(x)/x$ does not converge to a limit.